# Overriding SoftInputMode in fragment not working

Tags: android, fragment, scrollview

I have defined windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in Manifest activity tag and want different softInputMode in different fragment. Here is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**MyFragment**
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNSPECIFIED)

I tried multiple solution but didn't work for me. setSoftInputMode not overriding its taking default one which is defined in Activity class.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.